# Move files automatically to date folder

Tags: vba

from the below mentioned VBA code i am able to move files from Source to destination, however after moving the files i need to change the folder name by date everyday, is there anyway we can move the files directly to the updated date folder, the pattern of the folder name/folder date is

```
01102022
02102022
03102022
```

the code i have is

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveFilesTEST()

    Const sFolderPath As String = "E:\Asianet2"
    Const dFolderPath As String = "E:\Asianet3"
    Const FilePattern As String = "*.*"
    
    MoveFiles sFolderPath, dFolderPath, FilePattern

End Sub

Sub MoveFiles( _
        ByVal SourceFolderPath As String, _
        ByVal DestinationFolderPath As String, _
        Optional ByVal FilePattern As String = "*.*")
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(SourceFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The source folder path '" & SourceFolderPath _
            & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(DestinationFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The destination folder path '" & DestinationFolderPath _
            & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim apSep As String: apSep = Application.PathSeparator
    
    Dim sPath As String: sPath = SourceFolderPath
    If Left(sPath, 1) <> apSep Then sPath = sPath & apSep
        
    Dim sFolder As Object: Set sFolder = fso.GetFolder(sPath)
    If sFolder.Files.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dPath As String: dPath = DestinationFolderPath
    If Left(dPath, 1) <> apSep Then dPath = dPath & apSep
        
    Dim dFolder As Object: Set dFolder = fso.GetFolder(dPath)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sFile As Object
    Dim dFilePath As String
    Dim ErrNum As Long
    Dim MovedCount As Long
    Dim NotMovedCount As Long
    
    For Each sFile In sFolder.Files
        dFilePath = dPath & sFile.Name
        If fso.FileExists(dFilePath) Then
            dict(sFile.Path) = Empty
            NotMovedCount = NotMovedCount + 1
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
                fso.MoveFile sFile.Path, dFilePath
                ErrNum = Err.Number
                ' e.g. 'Run-time error '70': Permission denied' e.g.
                ' when the file is open in Excel
            On Error GoTo 0
            If ErrNum = 0 Then
                MovedCount = MovedCount + 1
            Else
                dict(sFile.Path) = Empty
                NotMovedCount = NotMovedCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next sFile
    
    Dim Msg As String
     
End Sub
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymf02.png)

Comment: And what is your question? Are you looking for [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) and [date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-function)?

Comment: I cannot understand what you try accomplishing... What does "i need to change the folder name by date everyday" mean? Should the code **change** the destination **Asianet3** folder name in  one  defined as "ddmmyyy" of the current day? Or you need to **create a new folder** named as mentioned before? And **should all the files from "sFolderPath" be "moved"  there**? Or what? Forget the code in this very moment, try better explaining **in words** what is to be done.

Comment: the current code moves the files to exact defined folder, but now i am willing to move the files to updated datewise folder i.e. When i run the command the code should move the files to updated date folder e.g. there are 10 folders with different dates, the code should see which folder have updated date and it should move the files in it automatically so i do not need to move files manually everyday

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru exactly rather than moving the files to Asianet3 folder it should move the files to current day folder.

Comment: Still not clear enough, at least, for me... So, are there already folders as **subfolders** of "dFolderPath" and you need to move the files from "sFolderPath" in the existing one being named as, for instance, **03102022**, in case of running the code today? Would such an understanding be a correct one? If not, please clarify...

Comment: Dear @faneduru yes correct.....    In Asianet3 folder i make subfolders datewise everyday, i am willing if there is any possibility that the files should be moved automatically in Asianet3 and then current day folder (current date folder e.g. 03102022) automatically so i do not need to move the files manually everyday

Comment: Why to move them firstly to "Asianet3" and **only after that** in current date folder? And why not creating the respective folder, **in code** just before copying the files? Don't you intend to move all existing files from "sFolderPath"?

Comment: Dear Fane Duru if it is possible to move files directly to current day folder it would be great, but maybe it needs to define the drive name as well e.g. "E Drive" "D Drive"

Comment: we archive the files in datewise folders that is why it requires to move the files finally into date folder, since our processes are 24 hours therefore i face difficulty in changing or moving files manually in date folder

Comment: This is not relevant related to your clarification discussion... I asked **, are there already folders AS SUBFOLDERS OF "dFolderPath" and you need to move the files from "sFolderPath"** and you said "Yes". So **are the folders named as the mention `Date` pattern SUBFOLDERS of "dFolderPath", or not**? If so, what "drive" are you talking about? If not, where the folders in discussion should/must exist? I only made a supposition and you confirmed it. Can you clarify this aspect, please?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, yes I make subfolders of current dates myself in Asianet3 folder. i have also added a screenshot in my question i hope this will clarify

Comment: So try to generate the path of _dFolderPath_ using your prefix path and date (and format)  function.

Comment: So, **you need moving all files from "sFolderPath" in newly created folder (it it does not exist) as subfolder of "dFolderPath"**. If this understanding is correct I will rapidly place an answer. Much more compact than you have now, using only VBA. Not VBScript objects as in your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next code. It creates the folder (as ddmmyyyy) in "dFolderPath" and moves all files existing in "sFolderPath":

```
Sub moveAllFilesInDateFolder()
 Dim DateFold As String, fileName As String
 Const sFolderPath As String = "E:\Asianet2"
 Const dFolderPath As String = "E:\Asianet3"
 
 DateFold = dFolderPath & "\" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")' create the folder if it does not exist
 If Dir(DateFold, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir DateFold
 
 fileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "\*.*")
 If fileName = "" Then MsgBox "No any file in " & sFolderPath & "...": Exit Sub
 
 Do While fileName <> ""
    Name sFolderPath & "\" & fileName As DateFold & "\" & fileName
    fileName = Dir
 Loop
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it...

You probably would need previously checking if there are no files in "dateFold", to avoid asking for overwriting in case of running the code twice (in the same day, by mistake)...

Comment: let me check and i will get back thanks

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru This is awsum, this works exactly as i was willing. not only this, this automatically creates the current date folder as well. Wonderful and thanks a lot.   I just need to ask if at 12:00 AM (midnight) when the date will be 04102022 will this code change the date to 04102022 automatically?? sorry if this is a lame question

Comment: @Salman Shafi Not sure I understand what you mean... If you run the code, for today date, which returned 03102022, after 12:00 AM the code will build a folder named 04102022. It will be tomorrow... Isn't it what you want?

Comment: dear @FaneDuru Yes exactly this is what i mean